# NB Store for DNN 6.2.5

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm using DNN 6.2.5 and the versions of NB Store available for download are not supported. So, can anyone please give me a link where I can download NB Store supported for DNN 6.2.5

Comment: How about the first link you'll get when googling `nb store dnn`: https://nbstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/106431

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
https://nbstore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/4010100c027b57e166ac309eeded09325d134343

Comparing the dates of publication of the NB_version and DNN 6.2.5 version seems it should work.
[image]